# Should I mark my iterator with DoesNotReturnAttribute if it never "yield breaks"?

Tags: c#, iterator, attributes

Is the use of DoesNotReturnAttribute here appropriate or not?

```
[DoesNotReturn]
public static IEnumerable<int> X()
{
    yield return 0;
    yield return 1;
    throw new Exception("Go away");
}
```

Comment: This method returns, always.

Comment: Note that even if the method were only `if (false) yield return 1;` and `throw new Exception("Go away");`, it will always return. Iterator methods always return an iterator, and so is the complete opposite of `[DoesNotReturn]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This returns, so no; you can see this [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGADAAQY4oDchJ5OAdACICWAhgOYB2EAzgC4swvBgGEIAExgBBLmwA2AT14teNArRxJyWUgAVCAb0KlTpANpMIMXgDkI/AEox+AVyhcAuibMYAzPTaFH4APCxc/AB8pAAaABQAlD6mxgRm6fQ45ADspMTqGb44WRi5OAWFpPwAFlAQAO6kXDCNAKIIYDAADoIQXHEARADiEKRs9WyKAwkVpgC+hHNAA=) - the `[DoesNotReturn]` ends up here:

```cs
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(1)]
    [IteratorStateMachine(typeof(<X>d__0))]
    [DoesNotReturn]
    public static IEnumerable<int> X()
    {
        return new <X>d__0(-2);
    }
```

where it clearly does return.

This seems like a missing warning, honestly. You *would* get a warning for simpler scenarios, or if you coded this manually.